# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - Node.Js, Express, Postgres

Tags: node.js, express, node-postgres

I'm having trouble with the error message in the title when trying to retrieve all users in my express .get('/users') method. I am using Node.js, Express, and node-postgres. I have my
`getUsers();` function defined in my queries.js file, and I call the function in my `app.get()` function in my index.js file.

**queries.js**

```
const client = require('./object models/db_client_pool')
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool(client.client)

async function getUsers(request, response) {
    await pool.connect()
    pool.query('select * from discord_users', (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
        response.sendStatus(200).json(results.rows)
        pool.release();

    })
}

module.exports = {
    getUsers
}
```

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();
//const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); deprecated
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const db = require('./queries');

app.use(express.json())

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.json({ info: 'Node.js, Express, and Postgres API' })
})

app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
    db.getUsers(req, res)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

As I said, I keep getting the "cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error and I'm at a loss of what to do. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from this:

```
response.sendStatus(200).json(results.rows)
```

to this:

```
response.status(200).json(results.rows);
```

or even just to this:

```
response.json(result.rows);    // 200 is the default status already
```

The last one is fine because 200 is already the default status so you don't need to set that yourself.

The problem is that `response.sendStatus(200)` sends a complete response with an empty body and then you try to call `response.json(result.rows)` which tries to send ANOTHER response to the same request.  Trying to send that second response to the same request is what triggers the error message you are getting.

`response.status(200)` just sets the status to 200 as a property on the waiting response object and waits for some other method to actually send the response itself which you can then do with `.json(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

So my guess is, you're running express 4.x and that doesn't support `response.sendStatus(200)` anymore. You have to use `response.status(200)` instead.

Now, another issue I see in your code is, I don't recognize `pool.release()` method from pg library. You can release a client back to a pool but you can't release a pool of clients. Maybe you meant `pool.end()`?

Comment: Yes I noticed that, I ended up taking it out and adjusting the code properly. Good eye!